# Can I use one layout with diffrent strings?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to make a book app with a list view of say 10 chapters but I don't want to make 10 activities and 10 layouts for these chapters isn't there a way for me to change the text view string based on with list item I chose that will use one layout but change strings depending on with list view item I chose. Recently began with java still at noob level I would really appreciate detailed explanations.

I am still a beginner so I don't really understand much about strings

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a reference to the TextView by setting this attribute within your textView in XML

android:id="@+id/textViewName

Once you have this you can tap into the android:text property programmatically and change it based on what chapter you're on.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I am a little lost what I am trying to do is have a list view with multiple chapters listed lets say 10 but I don't want each and every chapter to have a layout or activity I want them to use the same layout but different text depending on which chapter is chosen I don't want them all to be displayed at the same time I want them to be separate but use the same layout file instead of me having to create each and every chapter a layout.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! The method depends on the element you'll use

Or just replace bellow "Book.CurrentChatpter.title" by your title

If you want to change the **ActionBar**'s text :

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setTitle(Book.currentChatpter.title);
```

for a **TextView**'s text:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
tv.setText(Book.currentChatpter.title);
```

Thanks Mike ! Edited the TextView's id

Comment: Also, Remember to set the ID of your textView, as this will not default to textView1

Comment: Thanks for replying but I am a little lost what I am trying to do is have a list view with multiple chapters listed lets say 10 but I don't want each and every chapter to have a layout or activity I want them to use the same layout but different text depending on which chapter is chosen I don't want them all to be displayed at the same time I want them to be separate but use the same layout file instead of me having to create each and every chapter a layout.

Comment: Hey There ! So I'd recommend using a [layout adapter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#AdapterViews);  

You want to display chapters informations; 
You'll define a Class Chapter with attribut like Title, NPages (etc)

Then you define a new public class Adapter named ChaptersAdapter, it can extends any Adapter you'd like.

Then, when this Adapter is nice attach it to a view, a layout or anything;

Be Carefull, your adapter need to extends from another correct adapter for the view it's attached to.

You'll attach a GridAdapter to a GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways you can achieve this :
1. Page array list  -> keep next and previous button an keep the current index reference to navigate back forth on click event.

2. Show horizontal recycler view list contain book pages list items